# Genexus 18 usercontrol uploadfiles freeze with múltiple filess

Tags: file, upload, user-controls, genexus

When I try to upload multiple files with the usercontrol, it freezes and won't upload. If I cancel the upload of the files in the list and leave only one, it uploads without any problem. It only works with an archive.
This happens with genexus 17 and 18, with version 16 it works fine.
All projects in the same iis 8 and are made with .net environment.
Does anyone know if this has a solution?

I have tried to reproduce the version 18 project environment in Genexus 17 and 16.
It only works with version 16.

After doing diferent tests...
I discovered that it only happens with https.
With http it works correctly.

With https I can upload multiple files but very small in size....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is disable https/2 in iis 10 site.
You can edit bindings and check disable https/2

All works fine.